# Lowest brightness setting turns backlights off

Tags: laptop, screen, brightness, backlight

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 on a Laptop.

When I turn my brightness to the lowest setting it actually turns my backlights off and my entire screen goes black as if my computer was turned off. I have been finding this rather annoying because if I am holding down the keyboard shortcut to turn the brightness down and I don't stop just before I get to the lowest setting my entire screen just goes! Of course if I turn the brightness back up again then the screen comes back on.

But I was wondering if this is some sort of bug or whether it is actually meant to turn the backlights off on the lowest brightness setting? And if there is a way that I can prevent it from turning the backlights of fully when I go to the lowest brightness setting, even if it is by getting it not to allow the lowest brightness setting?

---

**Information Update:**

I tried adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` option in my kernel boot parameter but that didn't work. Instead what it did after a restart was break my brightness control so that brightness was stuck at 100% all of the time and when trying to adjust it the little bar which tells me how much it is was stuck on a really low and inaccurate amount.

Comment: Have you used the "xbacklight" command before? Try adjusting the brightness to different levels using the keyboard shortcuts and then run "xbacklight -get" in the command line each time and add the results to your question. (Also, you can run the "xbacklight -set 50" to set it to a specific percentage). There is something happening with how the OS is handling the lowest brightness, so getting these numbers will  the investigation. You could run this command when the backlight completely turns off to see what the OS thinks the backlight is set to.

Comment: @crimsonspectre I am having this problem specifically with xbacklight. when I type `xbacklight -set 0` or decrease in increments down to 0 or below the screen turns completely off

Comment: @Zanna, is the screen going black gradual (i.e. at 5% brightness it is almost completely black) or sudden (at 5% brightness, it is still fairly bright but at 0% the screen goes completely off)?

Comment: @crimsonspectre it goes very low at -set 5 as you'd expect, but totally off at 0. I want to map F5 to turn down but stop it going off entirely

Comment: Made a chatroom to discuss further :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39790/backlight-issues

Comment: fixed in later version? maybe this is no-repro now...

Comment: @Zanna: Although it is an EOL version, and the issue appears to be fixed in later versions. After many discussions on Meta I have found that if it was on-topic when it was asked then it always remains to be. Even if in newer versions the issue was fixed, it's not fixed on 14.10. Seems a silly rule to me, but anyway...

Comment: But we can close your question if it is no repro :)

Comment: @Zanna: Except for it is reproducible, but on the EOL release. You will find this amongst most of the EOL questions which are for some ridiculous reason not considered off-topic.

Comment: But it's unanswerable because we don't support EOL releases, so we aren't obliged to attempt to reproduce it in order to answer it...

Comment: @Zanna: Ah, but that is where you are mistaken, questions about EOL releases are supported as long as the question was asked before the release went EOL.

Comment: I know it's crazy, but I've had many an argument with the community and its mods and that's the way they want to keep it.

Comment: I think the question should be closed as irreproducible because the system with the issue was upgraded and doesn't have the same issue any longer, so we can't tell what would have fixed the problem.

Comment: I get this in Ubuntu 18.04 on a Samsung 900X laptop. Really bad if a deliberate choice, since you're stuck if you don't have/know the keyboard shortcut to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a normal feature, I have it too in Ubuntu 15.04. I actually quite like it: when I need to run something overnight on my laptop, it basically allows me to switch off the screen. Windows doesn't let me do this, I had to keep a large book over my laptop screen or change my power settings when I had to run overnight processes.

That being said, if you don't like it, why don't you just keep your brightness at a higher setting?

Comment: Well, now that I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 I do not actually get this, before when I wanted the brightness down but not for the screen to go off this would be annoying because my brightness controls change too quickly so the screen would turn off when I only wanted to turn down the brightness a little bit. Though I do have a 14.04 system with this problem and I would like to somehow fix it if I can.